# Where do initial task/kernel/cpu scheduler values after cold boot come from in Linux?

Tags: linux, configuration, task-scheduler

This question is related to [a former one](https://serverfault.com/questions/908211/what-are-all-most-ways-to-enable-disable-usage-of-async-file-io-in-linux), which contains the full background of my problem. The summary of that background is that I have two almost identical VMs and one of those is scaling very badly under some CPU intensive workloads with I think at least some I/O involved. So what I'm doing now is comparing outputs of `sysctl -a` for both VMs and researching on differences.

One of those differences is regarding the task scheduler, the initial values after a cold boot on the problematic VM are much higher than on the other one. ***So I'm wandering where those values come from initially?*** E.g. if they are calculated, which facts they depend on, maybe the VM-host, if they change on runtime automatically etc. ***Estimations about if those different values could have any reasonable impact on overall scaling of a system at all are welcome as well.***

The following are examples for different values, while I only provide one of the 8 vCPUs and overall scheduler settings. The important parts for each vCPU look very similar.

Good vs. Bad VM:

```
--- C:/Users/tschoening/Desktop/Good VM.txt Mi 18. Apr 19:24:47 2018
+++ C:/Users/tschoening/Desktop/Bad VM.txt  Mi 18. Apr 19:24:44 2018
@@ -8,3 +8,3 @@ kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.imbalance_pct = 1
-kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_interval = 4
-kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_newidle_lb_cost = 75519
-kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.min_interval = 2
+kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_interval = 16
+kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_newidle_lb_cost = 155384
+kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.min_interval = 8
@@ -15 +15 @@ kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.wake_idx = 0
-kernel.sched_latency_ns = 12000000
+kernel.sched_latency_ns = 24000000
@@ -17 +17 @@ kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 500000
-kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 1500000
+kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 3000000
@@ -25 +25 @@ kernel.sched_tunable_scaling = 1
-kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 2000000
+kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 4000000
```

Good VM:

```
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_factor = 32
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_idx = 2
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 1
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.flags = 4143
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.idle_idx = 1
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.imbalance_pct = 125
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_interval = 4
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_newidle_lb_cost = 75519
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.min_interval = 2
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.name = DIE
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.wake_idx = 0

kernel.sched_latency_ns = 12000000
kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 500000
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 1500000
kernel.sched_nr_migrate = 32
kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms = 25
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
kernel.sched_shares_window_ns = 10000000
kernel.sched_time_avg_ms = 1000
kernel.sched_tunable_scaling = 1
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 2000000
```

Bad VM:

```
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_factor = 32
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_idx = 2
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 1
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.flags = 4143
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.idle_idx = 1
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.imbalance_pct = 125
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_interval = 16
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_newidle_lb_cost = 155384
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.min_interval = 8
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.name = DIE
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.wake_idx = 0

kernel.sched_latency_ns = 24000000
kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 500000
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 3000000
kernel.sched_nr_migrate = 32
kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms = 25
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
kernel.sched_shares_window_ns = 10000000
kernel.sched_time_avg_ms = 1000
kernel.sched_tunable_scaling = 1
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 4000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer elsewhere, which I would like to document and link that thread:

> The initial values are based on your hardware and suggested default values. If the servers are different, ie. different memory, processor; the default values can be different. None of what I see here is going to make much real-world difference. I know the numbers look a lot different, but in real-world terms they're not.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/where-do-initial-task-kernel-cpu-scheduler-values-after-cold-boot-come-from-4175627988/#post5845481

Besides that, I know for sure now that most of the differences simply come from the fact that one VM had 2 and the other 8 vCPUs at the moment I executed `sysctl -a`. There's most likely no wrong global setting or such, like I assumed. I see exactly the same different values for e.g. `*_interval` and `sched_*_ns` using some Ubuntu 14.04 I had on my desktop in VMware Workstation with 2 and 8 vCPUs. Complete different hardware, VMs etc., same numbers.